# C++: How to get the address of a float pointer and convert it to void**

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

In C++ programming, I often need to acquire the address of a pointer and convert it to `void **`. For example, typically when using CUDA:

```
int main() {
    float *data;
    size_t size = sizeof(float) * 1024;

    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMalloc((void **)&data, size));   // question about this line
    ...
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaFree(static_cast<void *>(data)));

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that the cast of a `float **` to `void **` using C-style type cast irks me, as I don't want to use that in C++ programming.

So far, I've been using `reinterpret_cast<void **>(&data)` instead, but I'm not happy with it. For some reason I don't think this is the proper way to do it.

I tried doing `&static_cast<void *>(data)` once very stupidly, as this obviously fails for trying to get the address from a rvalue.

I've done some search on Google and Stack Overflow, but I'm having a hard time finding good keywords for the query.

I've also been learning the concept of rvalue reference, but I don't think it was designed for this problem.

So my question is, what is the proper C++ way to cast from `float **` to `void **` in this context? Also, is there a way to `static_cast` to `void *` and still get the address from the returned value, like rvalue reference? (PS: I still don't quite understand rvalue reference, so forgive me if this is a rookie mistake)

**Edit** --------------

Sorry I didn't make myself clear. I don't want to declare a `void *` here. I just want to somehow doing a 'proper' C++ cast to get this done, preferably in just one line.

**More Edit** ----------

I do understand that using a `void *` the proper way, as @M.M pointed out below (in fact, that's precisely what I've been doing for some time now). I'm just curious if there is any proper way that avoids using `void *`.

Comment: Using `reinterpret_cast<void**>(&data)` *is* the "proper" way to cast here.

Comment: Why does this library take `void **` parameters where a `void *` would do just fine ?

Comment: @SidS • looks like it is a C API equivalent of a `void*&` parameter in C++.

Comment: @SidS it's an "out" parameter, the function "returns" a `void *` value and uses the function return value for error codes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
void *newdata;
CUDA_CHECK(cudaMalloc(&newdata, size));
float *data = static_cast<float *>(newdata);

CUDA_CHECK(cudaFree(data)); // or pass newdata, doesn't matter
```

And obviously I'd wrap those chunks up into a smart pointer with RAII.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear in the OP. I know this is a good way to do it. But what if I don't want to use a `void *` pointer? I'm wondering if there is any way to avoid this. Editing the OP now...

Comment: @TerryTsao This answer shows the proper way. The version with `reinterpret_cast` (which is exactly equivalent to the C-style cast) is undefined behaviour that "should work"  ,  it seems your spidey senses are indeed telling you that it is not good to rely on the UB working

Comment: @M.M Thank you for your comment. I was thinking the exact same thing.